# How to ask formally - please suggest a course of action?

Tags: business-language

Can someone please suggest an alternative way of asking business stakeholders:

> "Please suggest a necessary course of action"

...after a part of their plan was rejected by higher authorities.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As alternatives to "suggest a necessary course of action," you might consider:

- Please develop a plan of action to address the identified deficiencies.
- Please propose an alternate course of action that addresses these concerns.
- Please revise your submission to address the issues identified by management.
- Please review the attached reasons for rejection and resubmit your plan with revisions to address these concerns.